# Filemaker Pro won't run script triggers while importing

Tags: filemaker

I'm using Filemaker Pro 12 Advanced.  I have a few tables but have really only been working with a couple.  I set an onObjectSave script trigger to run on a field called departmentName.  When I import an excel spreadsheet it adds records that include this field but it doesn't run the script.

My question is whether or not importing runs scripts and then also how I can then get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing does not trigger scripts. However, you can write a looping script after the import finishes to run the script for each record.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  I just have a button now I have to press after each time I import.